# Where does pre-commit install "environments"?

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm trying to setup [`pre-commit`](https://pre-commit.com/) for a Python project's repository. Upon running `pre-commit install` I see an output like this:

```
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/asottile/seed-isort-config.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-isort.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-pylint.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
```

What are these "environments" and where are they being installed to?

Comment: note that your output must've come from `pre-commit install --install-hooks` or `pre-commit install-hooks` or `pre-commit run`, as `pre-commit install` by itself *does not install environments*

Comment: I did run just `pre-commit install` to get that output, as I can see it in my Bash history.

Comment: trust me, that's not possible -- I'm the author

Answer (score 56):

The environments are installed into [a cache](https://pre-commit.com/#managing-ci-caches):

> `pre-commit` by default places its repository store in `~/.cache/pre-commit` -- this can be configured in two ways:
>
> - `PRE_COMMIT_HOME`: if set, `pre-commit` will use that location instead.
> - `XDG_CACHE_HOME`: if set, `pre-commit` will use `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/pre-commit` following the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

---

disclaimer: I am the author

Comment: What happens if we delete it, can you add a command to reset (rebuild the cached env from scratch)?

Comment: you're looking for [`pre-commit install-hooks`](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-install-hooks) or [`pre-commit install --install-hooks`](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-install)

Comment: Thanks, I believe there's a bug however. I deleted `'/Users/myname_usr/.cache/pre-commit/repoabwuil1n/`, and the mypy/pre-commit integration still continues to look here, despite no mention of `repoabwuil1n` anywhere in the config. do you know how I can force it to start from scratch?

Comment: not sure what you expected when you delete random stuff willy nilly from a managed directory :P.  `pre-commit clean` is the intended interface

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it! `pre-commit clean` is idempotent, good job :) 

Also, for posterity: when you update a requirements3.txt, make sure to update the ` .pre-commit-config.yaml`, otherwise if you have e.g. `mypy` hooks, it will use the old env dependencies

Comment: pre-commit does not install from requirements files (or any file other than `.pre-commit-config.yaml` in the repository under test) so that advice isn't really relevant

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this documentation section: [Managing CI Caches](https://pre-commit.com/#managing-ci-caches)