# How to copy pre-commit?

Tags: pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I want to install pre-commit to a Linux machine that doesn`t have access to the Internet so hooks can`t be downloaded. I made a copy of `.pre-commit-config.yaml` on another machine then did `pre-commit` all hooks were installed. But where all of them are stored? How can I copy them?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does pre-commit install "environments"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539288/where-does-pre-commit-install-environments)

Comment: generally hooks aren't portable between machines -- but I've linked a duplicate with the answer