# Why does pre-commit fail with "failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.10'"?

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I've just started using `pre-commit` in a project I've been working on for a few weeks. I defined my .pre-commit-config.yaml

```yaml
---
# See https://pre-commit.com for more information
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.5.0
    hooks:
      - id: check-json
      - id: check-merge-conflict
      - id: end-of-file-fixer
      - id: check-yaml
      - id: trailing-whitespace

  - repo: https://github.com/ambv/black
    rev: 23.11.0
    hooks:
      - id: black
        language_version: python3.10

  - repo: https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff-pre-commit
    # Ruff version.
    rev: v0.1.6
    hooks:
      # Run the linter.
      - id: ruff
      # Run the formatter.
      - id: ruff-format

  - repo: https://github.com/igorshubovych/markdownlint-cli
    rev: v0.37.0
    hooks:
      - id: markdownlint
        args: ["--config", ".github/linters/.markdownlint.json"]

  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.7.0
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        name: mypy tests
        files: ^tests/
```

When I run pre-commit it fails with this error:

> [INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/ambv/black.
> [INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
> [INFO] This may take a few minutes...
> An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/usr/local/Cellar/pre-commit/3.4.0/libexec/bin/python', '-mvirtualenv', '/Users/redacted/.cache/pre-commit/repoljj12k4y/py_env-python3.10', '-p', 'python3.10')
> return code: 1
> stdout:
> RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.10'
> stderr: (none)
> Check the log at /Users/jamiethomson/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log

I simply don't understand why this is happening. I think its trying to create a virtualenv at **/Users/redacted/.cache/pre-commit/repoljj12k4y/py_env-python3.10**, but I don't know why. I can confirm that that directory does not exist:

```bash
> ls /Users/redacted/.cache/pre-commit/repoljj12k4y/py_env-python3.10                                                   
"/Users/redacted/.cache/pre-commit/repoljj12k4y/py_env-python3.10": No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I'm on a mac by the way, and I use pyenv to manage python versions, in case that matters.

I assume that directory location is stored in some config somewhere but I've looked for such a thing and I can't find it. Does anyone know why pre-commit would be trying to create a virtualenv at this location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pre-commit [installs tools in isolated environments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62539288/812183) to avoid interfering with user space, to avoid conflicting tools, and to ensure consistent installation of exactly what's requested

in this case you've requested `language_version: python3.10` and so pre-commit will attempt to create an environment using `python3.10`

the error message comes from `virtualenv` and indicates that *you do not have python 3.10 available*

the directory does not exist after your execution because the installation is cleaned up on failure

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Thx Anthony, and thank you for pre-commit